# Why does one CTRL-Z when running in gdb keep giving SIGTSTP signal each time I use 'cont' command?

Tags: linux, api, linux-kernel, gdb, pthreads

I'm working on an project on `Ubuntu Linux`, when I  debug the application using `GDB` and break by `CTRL + Z`, I got `SIGTSTP` and the `GDB` interrupt as expected.

But when I using `cont` after that, I still got `SIGTSTP`, I repeat `cont` a lot of time, but seams it just behaviour the same, and just repeatedly give me `SIGTSTP`.

Following two call stack alternatively repeat:

```
The call stack is as following alterativly:
Program received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user).
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffef73d700 (LWP 32591)]
0x00007ffff636dffd in read () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff636dffd in read () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6301ff8 in _IO_file_underflow () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff630303e in _IO_default_uflow () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff62f718a in _IO_getline_info () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff62f606b in fgets () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
... .... .... ....
#11 0x00007ffff664ee9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff637b3fd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#13 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Program received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user).
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffeef3c700 (LWP 32592)]
0x00007ffff6374763 in select () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6374763 in select () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
... ... ... ...
#6  0x00007ffff664ee9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff637b3fd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

So can any reason for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`gdb` usually (it's configurable) arranges to stop the program and regain control of the terminal when a signal is about to be received by the program.

`gdb` usually (it's configurable) sends the signal to the program when you resume execution.

The settings can be seen with the `info signals` command.

```
(gdb) info signals
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program Description
SIGINT        Yes   Yes     No              Interrupt
...
SIGTSTP       Yes   Yes     Yes             Stopped (user)
...
```

In this case,

- typing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> will stop the program, and `continue` will resume it without sending any signal to it.
- typing <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> will stop the program, and `continue` will resume it accompanied by a SIGTSTP signal, so it will immediately stop again. If you type `continue` again, it should resume.

There are two ways to have the program resume without delivering a SIGTSTP signal to it.

The first is to use the `handle SIGTSTP nopass` command, which will change the "Pass to program" flag to "No".

The second is to use the `signal` command instead of `continue`. From the built-in help:

```
(gdb) help signal
Continue program with the specified signal.
Usage: signal SIGNAL
The SIGNAL argument is processed the same as the handle command.

An argument of "0" means continue the program without sending it a signal.
This is useful in cases where the program stopped because of a signal,
and you want to resume the program while discarding the signal.
```

So, `signal 0` will resume the program without the SIGTSTP signal being delivered to it.

Comment: +1 for mension `info signals` which I didn't know before. But this still not resolved my issue.

Comment: So if you type `signal 0`, you immediately see the program stopped again by SIGTSTP?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use  Ctrl+C  (SIGINT) for interuppting a running process  and  set breakpoints.

I think this would be helpful
http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/gdb_toc.html#SEC40

Comment: But seams Ctrl+C doesn't work on my linux terminal. It just do nothing. Any possible reason?

Comment: Can you check keybindings for terminal. I guess this option is already being used somwhere else. This is unsual. Since default mapping for copy is also Ctrl+Shift+C.

Answer (score 0):

This is much after the OP but if anyone else lands here:
I got this when debugging a gRPC application with many threads, where I stopped it using Ctrl-z. I had to run
`handle SIGTSTP nopass nostop`
to make `continue` actually resume execution in all threads.